# Инициализация с помощью проинициализированной переменной

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Здравствуйте, начал решать задачу на masm32, возник следующий вопрос:

```
Pw equ 0b7e15163h
S0 dd Pw
S1 dd S0
```

В результате трансляции S0 инициализируется константой Pw, а S1 - офсетом S0, мне же хочется проинициализировать её именно значением S0, а не адресом, возможно ли это в MASM? Пример, конечно же, иллюстративный и не имеет практического смысла. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Меняйте логику программы!

Answer (score 1):

Т.е. написать что-то (по сишному) `S1 dd *S0` ?

В общем случае - нет. В Вашем - можно написать

```
S0 dd Pw
S1 dd Pw
```

Да и с какой бы радости таким возможностям быть - они сильно перегружали бы ассемблер. А это должна быть простая программа - бо для написания чего-нибудь сложного лучше использовать другие языки.

Comment: Для этого скобки есть: dword ptr [S0]. Ссылки адресуются через Offset.

Comment: Ассемблер нужен не для того, чтобы что-то простое сделать. Ассемблер полноценен. Другое дело, что не всегда возможно подставить правильное значение или правильный адрес на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Следует понимать разницу между переменными скрипта и реальными переменными. Вы этой разницы не понимаете, как и ТС.

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю ни того, ни другого. Нельзя ли продемонстрировать более развёрнутый код. Чтобы после трансляции или после линковки можно было увидеть желательное 63 51 E1 B7 63 51 E1 B7 (как я понимаю именно этого хотел Антон).

Comment: Indy, ТС вполне понимает разницу между переменными скрипта и переменными кода, более того, я не вижу в посте каких-то предпосылок к противоположному мнению. Вам следует пытаться транслировать то, что пытаетесь советовать, а также следует учиться читать. alexlz, да, именно это я и имел в виду.

Comment: alexlz, тут нет общего и частного случаев, повторюсь, вопрос был не о том, как мне присвоить переменной S1 значение Pw, а о том, как проинициализировать значением переменной S0 переменную S1.

Comment: А что такое TC? Кстати, ник у меня чуть-чуть иначе пишется.

Comment: А попонятней можно? Что такое переменная (в асме)? Если участки памяти (инициализирумые по dd) должны иметь одинаковое содержимое, то это одно. А если имеется в виду что-либо другое, то так и надо написать. И что такое переменные скрипта?

Comment: alexlz, извините, неправильно разглядел.
ТС, я так понимаю, - Топик Стартер.
Думаю, что мы с вами одинаково понимаем переменные как участки памяти. Indy, судя по всему что-то путает с переменными, которые являются частью макросредств языка.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы хотите, чтобы эту инициализацию сделал компилятор? А что мешает сделать uberinitfunction, которая будет вызываться заранее и правильно инициализировать переменные?

Comment: Я вообще извращенец - сейчас предпочитаю код такого рода писать на gcc + gas.

Comment: Не знаю, что такое uberinitfunction, но смысл изначальной головоломки, как я понимаю, провести желаемую инициализацию без дополнительного кода. Это, опять же по моему разумению, можно сделать только с помощью макросредств. Возможно, что таких макробиблиотек и существует много, но мне эти новшества полувековой давности (был даже С-- - не путать с современным C--) неинтересны. А писать для x86 на gas - действительно изврат :)